# Esper: Grammatically defining a type with sub types?

Tags: java, esper

I have to define the class below in ESPER so I'm able to reference the sub-types and internal arrays. I have to do it pragmatically. I don't care how:

**UPDATE**: **The complete class**:

```
 public class IoTEntityEvent implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private IoTProperty[] Properties;
    private String About;

    IoTEntityEvent (){
        this.About = null;
        this.Properties = null;
    }
    public String getAbout() {
        return About;
    }

    public void setAbout( String value){
        this.About = value;
    }
    public void setProperties(int index, IoTProperty value) {
        Properties[index] = value;
    }


    public IoTProperty getProperties(int index) {
        return Properties[index];
    }

    public void setProperties( IoTProperty[] value) {
        Properties = value;
    }


    public IoTProperty[] getProperties() {
        return Properties;
    }
}
```

This is the sub-class:

```
   public class IoTProperty implements java.io.Serializable {
        private Map<String,String>[] IoTStateObservation =null;
        private String About = null;

        IoTProperty (){
            this.About = null;
            this.IoTStateObservation = null;
        }

        public String getAbout() {
               return About;
           }

        public void setAbout(String value) {
             About = value;
        }


        public Map<String,String>[] getIoTStateObservation() {
               return IoTStateObservation;
           }
        public void setIoTStateObservation( Map<String,String>[] value) {
             IoTStateObservation = value;
        }

        public Map<String,String> getIoTStateObservation(int index) {
            return IoTStateObservation[index];
        }
        public void setIoTStateObservation(int index, Map<String,String> value) {
            IoTStateObservation[0] = value;
        }
       }
```

I tried like this :

```
 eventNames[0] = "About";
 eventType[0] = String.class;

 eventNames[1] = "Properties";
 eventType[1] = IoTProperty[].class;

 epService.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().addEventType("type", eventNames, eventType);
```

This works but I can't access the sub-types. I also tried to define the sub type in similar manner. Can someone can explain how I suppose to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. I found out how and is as following:

```
epService.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().addEventType("type",IoTEntityEvent.class);
```

Then the event should be send like this without any casting:

```
IoTValue[] va=  {new IoTValue("0.62","2014-06-09T18:08:40.968Z","2014-06-09T18:08:40.968Z")};
IoTProperty[] pr = {new IoTProperty(va,"property")};
IoTEntityEvent event = new IoTEntityEvent(pr,"Entity");
epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "This works but I can't access the sub-types."
Tried like "select Properties[0].whatever" from type?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: By it works it mean that i'm able to query it and even do Properties[0]. But when I try to do Properties[0].About do not work. Also by it works I mean the return value in the underlying object contain the value of Properties[0].About, I just can't query it in esper.

Comment: Make sure you have lowercase properties. According to JavaBean "getAbout()" is "about" and not "About". You can also do a "admin.getConfiguration().getEventType("type") that returns an EventType object that tells you what properties exist i.e. getPropertyNames()

Answer (score 0):

According to the Esper documentation:

> Plain-old Java object events are object instances that expose event properties through JavaBeans-style getter methods. Events classes or interfaces do not have to be fully compliant to the JavaBean specification; however for the Esper engine to obtain event properties, the required JavaBean getter methods must be present or an accessor-style and accessor-methods may be defined via configuration.

In short, you need to create the JavaBean getters and setters in order to access your private members.

Comment: Thank you for you response, I did! I paste the full code so you can see the getters and setters

Comment: You need to have a method "public Property[] getProperties() { return properties; }" in order to conform to JavaBean. You should be able to access them like "event.properties[x]" in esper.